# dual purpose package and MajorUpgrade

Tags: installshield, windows-installer, basic-msi

I'm trying to make a dual purpose package and I have problems with the upgrade.

by default my property are
`ALLUSERS=2` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1`

on the dialog `readyToInstall` if the "install for all users" is checked, I use SetProperty to put `ALLUSERS=1` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER={}` (just to be sure).

that part work fine, the registry are set in HKLM and the files in Program Files.

during upgdrade however ...
I have a custom action that check after the `AppSearch` if the keys are in HKLM it set `ALLUSERS=1` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER={}`.

if I make a minor update, the files are upgraded correctly.

if I make a major update, the registries are still in the HKLM but the files switch to `LocalAppData` (it follows the default value in fact), ignoring the fact that I force the `ALLUSERS` to 1 after the `AppSearch`.
(I even try to force it after the migrate feature state just to mimic the UI but it didn't worked either).

is there a way to make a major upgrade with dual purpose package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following excerpt, it seems that you're facing scenario B:

> **Major Upgrades can Fail**
>   If you use the Upgrade code feature of Windows Installer to perform a
>   major upgrade the detection of the existing software will fail if: (a)
>   the original software was installed with `ALLUSERS=””` and the new
>   software has `ALLUSERS=1` in its Property table or passed on the command
>   line or (b) the original software was installed with `ALLUSERS=1` and
>   the new software has `ALLUSERS=””` or `ALLUSERS` is not defined in the
>   Property table or on the command line.

**For more info:** https://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/understanding-per-user-or-per-machine-context-for-application-setup-packages/